# Scala error : NoClassDefFoundError, UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-native-interface

Good morning. I am creating a spark application with scala. Seven
 You must run shared library (libfreebayes.so) in a distributed node environment. libfreebayes.so runs an external program written in c ++ called freebayes. However, the following errors occur:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/libfreebayes.so already loaded in another classloader

The CreateFreebayesInput method must be done on a partition-by-partition basis. Is there a problem loading libfreebayes.so for each partition? This application works properly in spark local mode. How do I get it to work in yarn-cluster mode? I can not sleep because of this problem. Help me. :-<

```
import java.io.{File, FileReader, FileWriter, PrintWriter}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{HashPartitioner, SparkConf, SparkContext}

object sparkFreebayes {

  def main(args : Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkFreebayes")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val appId = sc.applicationId
    val appName = sc.appName
    val referencePath="/mnt/data/hg38.fa"
    val input = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val executerNum = args(1).toInt
    val outputDir = args(2)

    val inputDir = "/mnt/partitionedSam/"
    val header = input.filter(x => x.startsWith("@"))

    val body = input.filter(x => !x.startsWith("@"))
    val partitioned = body.map{x => (x.split("\t")(2),x)}.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new tmpPartitioner(executerNum)).persist()
    val cHeader = header.collect.mkString("\n")
    val sorted = partitioned.map( x => (x._2) )
    CreateFreebayesInput(sorted)

    def CreateFreebayesInput(sortedRDD : RDD[String]) = {

      sortedRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) =>
        val tmp = iter.toList
        val outputPath = outputDir+"/"+appId+"_Out_"+idx+".vcf"
        val tmp2 = List(cHeader) ++ tmp
        val samString = tmp2.mkString("\n")
        val jni = new FreeBayesJni
        val file = new File(inputDir + "partitioned_" + idx + ".sam")
        val fw = new FileWriter(file)
        fw.write(samString)
        fw.close()

        if (file.exists() || file.length()!=0) {
          System.loadLibrary("freebayes")
          val freebayesParameter = Array("-f","/mnt/data/hg38.fa",file.getPath,"-file",outputPath)
          jni.freebayes_native(freebayesParameter.length,freebayesParameter)
          //runFreebayes(file.getPath, referencePath, outputPath )
        }
        tmp2.productIterator
      }
    }.collect()
  }
}
```

FreeBayesJni class is next :

```
class FreeBayesJni {

  @native def freebayes_native(argc: Int, args: Array[String]): Int;
}
```

my spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --class partitioning --master yarn-cluster ScalaMvnProject.jar FullOutput_sorted.sam 7 /mnt/OutVcf
```

thank you.

Comment: agreed with comment above about needing c++ lib on all nodes, either locally or through NFS or some other way of mounting it. Spark does handle spreading jar files across network if configured correctly but I don't think it will handle the so file for you. I wrote this answer about an older version of spark, not directly related to your question but you might find something useful in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502774/3255525

Comment: There is a library in the correct path for each node.